# My questions were serially downvoted, automatic reversal didn't kick in and flagging one of the questions did not help

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

A week ago, after downvoting the answer to the question [Unable to get attributes back from GetCustomAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510703/unable-to-get-attributes-back-from-getcustomattributes/11510721#11510721), four of my questions were downvoted and on the other day, another three met the same fate.

> [image: Downvotes history]

I've suspected this to be a case of serial downvoting, since *all* of my questions I ever had on SO (at the time of downvotes) were downvoted. After waiting two days for automatic reversal to kick in, I've flagged one of the questions ( [Why is it necessary to load every argument onto the stack in CIL method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471608/why-is-it-necessary-to-load-every-argument-onto-the-stack-in-cil-method) ) and explained the situation in the flag. The flag was marked as helpful, but so far, I did not get the reputation back.

Is there something else I could do, or should I just keep waiting?

Comment: FYI, moderators don't have the power to reverse votes. I think only devs can do that. But what the moderator *can* do is warn or suspend the downvoter if they can determine who it is.

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks, didn't know that. In general, I completely understand that this downvoting case is not *that* severe (I've only lost 14 rep points) and therefore it's probably somewhere on the end of somebody's TODO list. I just want to make sure that it *is* on that list, I don't care where :)

Comment: You got another five yesterday, looks like somebody's really angry. With the short intervals between the votes, it reeks quite strongly of serial downvoting.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, those five were automatically reverted within few hours, though - maybe the reversal system kicks in with five consecutive downvotes?

Comment: The same thing happened to me last month (only it wasn't repeated). Since the script isn't reversing it, this must be a case of sock-puppeteering and/or collusion amongst other users (the former more likely). I suppose that makes it harder for anything to be done.

Comment: We could start a neighborhood watch. Not that that would have any effect, but at least we would have a reason to run around with [weaponry](http://ilol.co/upload_pic/3396.jpg).

Comment: Five may be the threshold, but nobody will officially state the limit, the reversal script would be useless if there was easily findable information on its exact workings.

Comment: @Bart: I demand a unicorn to ride around on!

Comment: These happen quite often. On May 11: [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1053621/john) downvoted the top three answers of [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) in response to a [(now deleted) comment on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548407/can-anyone-explain-this-behaviour). It was never reversed. ([Here's the relevant portion of chat where I came to this conclusion.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3665430#3665430))

Comment: @Mysticial: 3 downvotes is hard to call "serial". It's just someone being a jerk. It would be bad if 3 downvotes triggered this script.

Comment: @NicolBolas: If one received only a hand full of downvotes over several years, three in a row on unrelated postings is almost certainly unjustified serial downvoting. And jerks should be banned from the site, or receive a warning first.

Answer (score 12):

When there are only a few votes involved, it can sometimes be difficult for us to tell with certainty who might behind them. Those seven votes that you show above were not from the same user, as far as I can tell.

I do see that the set of downvotes you received yesterday were automatically reversed by the serial downvoting safeguards this morning. I can say that those votes were not from the same user (or users) who voted on your earlier posts, this was someone new. It looks like you have some fans.

There really isn't a lot we can do here, because there's no clear indication that there was a single user behind the original sets of votes. If this pattern continues, flag us again and we might be able to see if we can identify them then.

---

As an update, I looked into this some more and I believe I might have found a sock puppet responsible for these votes. Votes from that user have been removed, but this might not show up until tomorrow. Let me know then if this took care of the problem.

Comment: `-340  8 mins ago  removed  User was removed` - wow...

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for your effort! I will certainly keep you updated.

Comment: Almost 36 hours have passed now. The downvotes are still there.

Comment: @brad Larson : are there any measures in SO if some group of people make someone lose point deliberately ? like distributed down voting of a user.