# Is the script that reverses serial downvotes finicky?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes, serial-voting

A few days ago I noticed that I lost a few points when someone downvoted three answers of mine, each of which had a decent number of upvotes and were the accepted answer, in the span of about 20 seconds. I didn't think much about it and figured that if anything, the script that fixes serial downvotes would catch it. And indeed it did.

However the next day, it appears as if the same twit that did the downvoting did it again on the exact same questions in the same short span of time. No problem I thought, this dude is just wasting everyone's time as the script that ran the previous day would correct it again. Yet when I went to check it the next day, the downvotes remained and hadn't been reversed as they were the first time.

So my question is, is there a problem with the script that handles the serial downvote correction, or can the script be bypassed if you just repeat the same behavior? Also, does the  user that did the downvoting get a warning about their behavior, and if they are a repeat offender, does anything else happen?

Comment: If I'm seeing the same events you're talking about, serial votes were not reversed. The downvotes were simply undone and then again redone. Otherwise your rep history would have had a "serial downvotes reversed" event. Edit: hmm. though that is the correct time for the serial voting filter to run....weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [My questions were serially downvoted, automatic reversal didn't kick in and flagging one of the questions did not help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141031/my-questions-were-serially-downvoted-automatic-reversal-didnt-kick-in-and-flag)

Comment: Nah @SamuelLiew, not the case here I'd say.

Comment: @Bart - when the downvotes were removed, they were all at the exact same time, like script would do, not several seconds apart like someone would do via tabs.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, that is what I noticed. So it seems that it didn't really get marked as a serial downvote reversal. And perhaps that allows the voting again. That might even be a bug.

Comment: @Bart - As far as I'm aware, when the script invalidates votes or a developer does, it always shows as "serial voting reversed." This looks like the user themselves undid those votes, even with the weird timing.

Comment: @BradLarson Yeah, therefore my initial confusion. But really at that point the votes should have been locked in. I'm calling glitch. Heck, I might even give the wheel of blame a spin. ;)

Comment: @Bart +1 for wheel of blame. I love that show.